# Python + elasticSearch -> how to speed up slow query?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

The following code takes about 40 min to map 8 million records

```py
def scanMap(response):
    projection = []

    for hit in response:
        dt = datetime.strptime(hit.dt_transacao +
                            hit.hr_transacao, "%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S")
        dtAux = datetime.strptime(hit.dt_transacao, "%Y-%m-%d")
        obj = {'cnpj': hit.cnpj_estabelecimento,
            'date': hit.dt_transacao,
            # 'card': hit._source.nr_cartao,
            'time': (dt-dtAux).seconds,
            }
        projection.append(obj)
    return projection

def createLocalCache(query, csvpath):
    response = query.scan()
    projection = scanMap(response)
    dtFrame = pd.DataFrame.from_records(projection)
    dtFrame.to_csv(csvpath,index=None,header=None)


client = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'my server',
                         'port': 9200}], http_auth=(user, pass))

search = Search(using=client, index=myIndex) \
    .params(size=10000) \
    .filter("match", cd_produto=12) \
    .filter("exists", field="smallString") \
    .source([
        "date",
        "time",
        "smallString"
    ]) \

createLocalCache(search,"/Users/Leonardo/Desktop/purchases201903.csv")
```

Using postman, a 10k record query takes aprox 1sec, so a "dumb" aprox would yield 10minutes for all 8 million...

What can i do to speed this up?

Comment: don't request so many records at once.... paginate... you can't possibly send 8 million records over the wire in one shot

Comment: @bryan60 i believe that elastic search-dsl does that...given the `params(size=10000)`

Comment: of course it provides for pagination.  The point is that you should never be attempting to pull 8M records at once. So you don't actually have a query speed problem.  10k is already way too many IMO.  If you need to run analytics, then use aggregations. It's what they're for.

Comment: @bryan60 my elasticsearch (version 2.4) is too slow... its faster to "cache" the data in a csv and work with it... i have actually over 500 million records to pull... this one projection is 8million due to the filters...

Comment: what I'm saying is that elastic is NOT too slow. the problem is that you're pulling too many records at once.  You're not following elastic best practices at all

Comment: @bryan60, there's got to be something im doing wrong. Pulling 260mB of data should not be a 40min operation... as i said in the question, if 10k takes aprox 1sec, 8kk should be a 13min operation... not 40+

Comment: what you're doing wrong is REQUESTING TOO MANY RECORDS AT ONCE. the reason is because you're exhausting your elasticsearch server because on every request it allocates a heap of the same size before it fetches the data. Things don't scale linearly like you assume they do for this reason.  you NEED to request smaller amounts of records and scroll and treat your data as a stream when working with large amounts of data. otherwise you're going to grind your servers to a halt very quickly

Comment: read: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html

Comment: @bryan60 elasticsearch-dsl is supposed to do that, as i mention on my first comment (https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#pagination)

Comment: sorry, i can't continue this.  You're just not getting it.

Comment: You could take a look at logstach in order to generate .csv file (https://qbox.io/blog/how-to-export-data-elasticsearch-into-csv-file). Otherwhise i agree with Bryan, you should use scroll to do this king of thing. Moreover i am curious how es (as in v2.4) could be "slow" and i dont see how export a .csv could be "faster", what kind of querry do you send ?